# XSLT transformation with a element name change and value

Tags: xml, xslt

Help help to convert an XML using XSLT from

```
<Res> <body> <element>VERSION=0:1:1</element> <element>CLASS=2:1:1</element> <element>FUN=1:1:1</element> <element>ORG=0:1:1</element> <element>ID.002=4214980010224084:1:1</element> </body> </Res>
```

Output:

```
<Res> <body> <VERSION>0:1:1</VERSION> <CLASS>2:1:1</CLASS> <FUN>1:1:1</FUN> <ORG>0:1:1</ORG> <ID.002>4214980010224084:1:1</ID.002> </body> </Res>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Changing the element value works for me... but stuck with how to change the element name. Please assist me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the quick answer:

```html
<xsl:stylesheet 
version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/"> 
<Res>
<body>
<xsl:for-each select="Res/body/*">
<xsl:element name="{substring-before(., '=')}">
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(.,'=')"/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each>
</body>
</Res>
</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and it produces below output:

```html
<Res>
    <body>
        <VERSION>0:1:1</VERSION>
        <CLASS>2:1:1</CLASS>
        <FUN>1:1:1</FUN>
        <ORG>0:1:1</ORG>
        <ID.002>4214980010224084:1:1</ID.002>
    </body>
</Res>
```

Comment: Thank you very much.. i will check on it.